# CRM Dynamics 2015 Plugin Cast Error, Specified Cast Is not valid

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

Below is a snippet of the code for the plugin, I also added the WCF service to be consumed(code) as well.

PLUGIN CODE BELOW

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&  context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {

            Entity phoneCallEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (phoneCallEntity.LogicalName != "phonecall")
                return;

            if (context.MessageName == "Create")
            {
                try
                {

                    int NumberToCall = phoneCallEntity.Attributes.Contains("phonenumber") ? (int)phoneCallEntity.Attributes["phonenumber"] : 0;
                    int ReceiveCallOn = phoneCallEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_destination") ? (int)phoneCallEntity.Attributes["new_destination"] : 0;
                    string apiKey = phoneCallEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_apikey") ? phoneCallEntity.Attributes["new_apikey"].ToString() : null;
                    int fId = phoneCallEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_fid") ? (int)phoneCallEntity.Attributes["new_fid"] : 0;

                    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                    binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IService1";
```

Here i call the service

```
 binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
 EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:62009/Service1.svc");
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(binding, endPointAddress);
 client.WebCall(NumberToCall, ReceiveCallOn, apiKey, fId);
```

Above I call the WCF Service

```
public void WebCall(Int64 NumberToCall, Int64 ReceiveCallOn, string APIkey, int FID)
    {
        string url = string.Format("https://xxxx{0},{1},{2}", NumberToCall, ReceiveCallOn, APIkey, FID);
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
    }
```

Code snippet above is the actual WCF Service being consumed, So the issue is with the casting of the Number toi call and the `ReceiveCallOn` number, they are both cell phone numbers , in CRM they are a phone data type, any ideas why I cannot cast this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the field `phonenumber` from entity `phonecall` is `Single Type of Text` (with format `Phone`), this means that is a string (as your custom field if the field settings are the same) so your code can be:

```
string NumberToCall = phoneCallEntity.Contains("phonenumber") ? phoneCallEntity["phonenumber"].ToString() : "";
string ReceiveCallOn = phoneCallEntity.Contains("new_destination") ? phoneCallEntity["new_destination"].ToString() : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `Parse` or `TryParse`. Just casting to int will sometimes convert a `char` character to its `asci` value, or have an exception on `NULL` values. Since you are working with user input I guess the following should be saver. (if you absolutely want `int's` the below should be ok), I do however agree with the previous post\answer that you should look at working, with strings rather.

**so ...**

```
var NumberToCall =0;
var ReceiveCallOn =0;

if (phoneCallEntity.Contains("phonenumber"))
   int.TryParse(phoneCallEntity["phonenumber"].ToString(), out NumberToCall);
if (phoneCallEntity.Contains("new_destination") )
   int.TryParse(phoneCallEntity["new_destination"].ToString(), out ReceiveCallOn);
```

... just taking your parse exception into consideration .

**Or just `Parse`**

```
if (phoneCallEntity.Contains("phonenumber"))
{
    int NumberToCall = int.Parse(phoneCallEntity["phonenumber"].ToString());
}
if (phoneCallEntity.Contains("new_destination"))
{
    int ReceiveCallOn = int.Parse(phoneCallEntity["new_destination"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: there is one problem, the fields contains a string, and if inside this string there are spaces or symbols like + or - the parse will fail. The field must be casted to a string, what can be done after (cleaning or a direct cast to int) is not relevant to error he got